# Django: How to nest two serializers in each other?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to nest the profile serializer in my story serializer to access username, user picture, etc. within the story. The profile serializer contains the user detail serializer to access the username, user ID, etc.  The entire nesting therefore looks like this: User serializer -> profile serializer -> story serializer. But when I do this and retrieve a story, I get the error message:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `ProfileSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'user'.
```

I searched for possible solutions but they wehre not applicable for my situation.

**User Model:**

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    pass
```

**User Detail Serializer:**

```
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    
    model = User
    fields = ('username','id', )
```

**Profile Model:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics/')
  
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

**Profile Serializer:**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user = UserDetailSerializer ()
  class Meta:
     model = Profile
     fields = ('id', 'user', 'image', 'bio')
```

**Story Model:**

```
class Story (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Story Serializer:**

```
class StoryRetrieveSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = ProfileSerializer ()

    class Meta:
        model = Story 
        fields =  ('id','title', 'author')
```

Via the story API i want to get back someting like this:

```
id: 1
title: "Test Title"
author: {username: "Test Author" , user id:1 , user image: "path"} // here the nested profile serialzer should provide the data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Story.auther` is a Auth User instance, you should use **`UserDetail`** serializer instead of `ProfileSerializer`

```
class StoryRetrieveSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserDetailSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Story 
        fields =  ('id','title', 'author')
```

Update -1

```
class ProfileFooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'image', 'bio')


class UserFooDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileFooSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'profile')


class StoryRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserFooDetailSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'author')
```

Here, I have created new serializers to make the code cleaner.

Comment: Arakal Abu Thank you. And how do i get the information from my Profile into the SoryRetrieve Serializer? Do I need to create a new 'SerializerMethodField' that is providing the correct profile?

Comment: You can define those `Profile` model fields within the `UserDetailSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

For example,Consider below models,

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
```

Below tracks are serialized into album,

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```